# adjust text view text size to fit the textview size only if needed

Tags: android, textview

When using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` it ignores the default textSize attribute and automatically adjust the text size to fit the entire view size.

Is there a way to adjust the text size **only** if the text size doesn't fit the view's size?

For example, I've a textView with a text size set to 14sp
If the user increased their device font size to display size, the text becomes bigger and might not fit the textview size, so I need to make sure the text size will fit the textview after these changes

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can even add attributes like:
`android:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"`,
`android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"` and
`android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"` This will help you scale text sizes  according to user's settings.

Comment: Thanks, but this is scaling the text even it doesn't need to be scaled.
I'm looking for a way to scale the text size only if it doesn't fit the view size